# Binary flow in max flow problem

Tags: network-flow

is there a way ensure that there only is flow through vertices c and d and not e or through d and e and not c. But not both at the same time. With an simple extension it is possible to put also minimum constraints on the network but this does not seem to help us.
[image]

Comment: You could direct $c,e$ to a new vertex $z$ with capacity 1, and then connect $z$ to $t$. I'm not sure that's what you're looking for, though.

Comment: Is there a way... _by doing what_? Are we allowed to change the graph? Change the weights? It's unclear what rules you're operating with.